# floatrow - remove whitespace beneath figure

Tags: spacing, floatrow

I have a page layout with exactly 40 text lines and some small pictures to distribute throughout the text. When I arrange 2 pictures at the page bottom in a row via `floatrow` and specify their height as a multiple of lines, I see some extra whitespace below. By coincidence (or not) its height is 2*baseline. How can I chop it off? I need the pics to stick exactly at the bottom of the page, there will be no captions or another picture-related text.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,russian,open=any]{scrbook} 
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage[paperwidth=14.8cm, paperheight=21.0cm, top=1.1cm, bottom=1.8cm, twoside, inner=0.9cm, outer=1.8cm, bindingoffset=0.5cm, footskip=1cm, headsep=0cm, headheight=0cm, voffset=0cm, hoffset=0cm, marginparsep=0cm, marginparwidth=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{floatpag} 
\usepackage[leadingfraction=1.0]{savetrees}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.95}

\raggedbottom

\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt}

\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=empty}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyfoot[EC,OC]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 

\begin{document}

могилку-то рыть не придётся, земелькой сверху присыплють~--- и всё тебе тут...

--- Тьфу, типун тебе на язык, боярин Порфирий!

\begin{figure}[b]
\centering
\begin{floatrow}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}\label{}}{%
\includegraphics[height=17\baselineskip, width=3cm]{dummy}
}
\hspace{3cm}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}\label{}}{%
\includegraphics[height=17\baselineskip, width=3cm]{dummy}
}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

--- А ты чего думала, боярыня Варвара, что тебя сюда для остраст\-ки посадили, чтобы ты вдругорядь сплетни по городу не разносила?

--- Это кто сплетни разносит, глаза твои бесстыжие? Да ты на жёнушку свою разлюбезную погляди! Это не их ли с боярыней Серапеей за глаза сороками называют? А за какие бы это такие добродетели-то, а? Да я по сравнению с ними...

--- Да ты на мою жену шибко-то не наговаривай!..

--- Ты на себя погляди, боярыня Варвара, чего ты на нас-то...

--- Это я-то на себя глядеть должна...

--- Любопытной Варваре...

--- Ларишка, Ларишка, што они говорят, ашь?..

--- Боярыне Варваре, говорят, нос оторвали!

--- Это Антипкиной-то Варваре оторвали?!

--- Нет, боярина Абросима жене!

--- Ашь?.. Какого боярина жена брошила?..

--- Не бросила! А Абросима!!!

--- Што ты орёшь, глухая я, што ли? Ты шама определишь, што говоришь~--- то брошила, то не брошила, а потом ори на бабушку-то!

--- Я не глухая, Ларишка! Я прошто плохо шлышу!

--- Зато болтаешь хорошо, матушка!

--- А вы, боярин Никодим, на мою бабушку-то не кричите, на свою кричите!

--- А ты, девка, мала ещё мне указывать!..

--- Зато наш род от самого Синеуса идёт!

--- А ты чего думала, боярыня Варвара, что тебя сюда для остраст\-ки посадили, чтобы ты вдругорядь сплетни по городу не разносила?

--- Это кто сплетни разносит, глаза твои бесстыжие? Да ты на жёнушку свою разлюбезную погляди! Это не их ли с боярыней Серапеей за глаза сороками называют? А за какие бы это такие добродетели-то, а? Да я по сравнению с ними...

--- Да ты на мою жену шибко-то не наговаривай!..

--- Ты на себя погляди, боярыня Варвара, чего ты на нас-то...

--- Это я-то на себя глядеть должна...

--- Любопытной Варваре...

--- Ларишка, Ларишка, што они говорят, ашь?..

--- Боярыне Варваре, говорят, нос оторвали!

--- Это Антипкиной-то Варваре оторвали?!

--- Нет, боярина Абросима жене!

--- Ашь?.. Какого боярина жена брошила?..

--- Не бросила! А Абросима!!!

--- Што ты орёшь, глухая я, што ли? Ты шама определишь, што говоришь~--- то брошила, то не брошила, а потом ори на бабушку-то!

--- Да что ли я на \emph{вас}, бабушка, ору~--- я же ору оттого, что вы глухая, как пень, аж перед людями неудобно!

--- Я не глухая, Ларишка! Я прошто плохо шлышу!

--- Зато болтаешь хорошо, матушка!

--- А вы, боярин Никодим, на мою бабушку-то не кричите, на свою кричите!

--- А ты, девка, мала ещё мне указывать!..

--- Зато наш род от самого Синеуса идёт!

--- А ты чего думала, боярыня Варвара, что тебя сюда для остраст\-ки посадили, чтобы ты вдругорядь сплетни по городу не разносила?

--- Это кто сплетни разносит, глаза твои бесстыжие? Да ты на жёнушку свою разлюбезную погляди! Это не их ли с боярыней Серапеей за глаза сороками называют? А за какие бы это такие добродетели-то, а? Да я по сравнению с ними...

--- Да ты на мою жену шибко-то не наговаривай!..

--- Ты на себя погляди, боярыня Варвара, чего ты на нас-то...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, it works if I add `\vspace{-2\baselineskip}`, but since the whitespace is not **exactly** this big, I'd rather like have a more elegant solution instead of trying to adjust the cut-off by millimeters.